# How to href a local pdf file with relative path so that after saving webpage as pdf file and opening with pdf reader the link works?

Tags: html, pdf

I have a web page with links to some pdf files (stored on server). The user can save web page and pdf files keeping the relation. For this I create a "special version" of the web page with hyperlinks to local files, for example:

```
<a href='file:///c:/myfolder/mysubfolder/linked_file.pdf'>show linked_file (absolute path)</a>
<a href='file:///mysubfolder/linked_file.pdf'>show linked_file (relative path)</a>
```

User saves webpage as pdf with browser print function to folder, for example c:\myfolder\main_file.pdf and downloads the linked pdf files to subfolder, for example c:\myfolder\mysubfolder\linked_file.pdf

When opening main_file.pdf with Acrobat Reader he can open linked pdf files by clicking the link.
This works only with **absolute** path (first link). In macOS it is necessary to omit drive letter "c:/".

But with **relative** paths (second link) it doesn't work! Using absolute path is bad because there is no chance to put the pdf files in any other location. I know you can create pdf file with relative links using Adobe Acrobat.

My question is: How do I have do specify a link with **relative** path in html so that links in pdf created with print function of browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) are working locally in Windows or macOS? Or is this impossible?

Comment: Welcome in Stack Overflow! To help the community, please try to improve the question title to indicate your necessity, not what you tried to do. I've done my best to share an useful answer but trust me, I'm not sure that I've been in topic with your needs. Any clarification would be very useful. Also please try to make more evident some research efforts, or this question could risk to be closed.

Comment: Note that PDF do not support HTML. Probably you are using a library that converts HTML to PDF for commodity reasons, but that is not a native format for PDF, as far as I know. Please mention your "PDF export library" in the question, to help others in giving better answers.

Comment: I did mention the "PDF export library" in my question: "User saves webpage as pdf with browser print function".

Answer (score 0):

In general, loading web resources from mixed protocol is not possible, and that is a feature.

Further information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Once published, your website will be available under HTTP(+s). So, relative URLs will work, like `./file.stuff` (since they will be loaded under the same protocol) but other protocols will be just blocked (of course `file:///path/to/file.stuff` will be blocked in most circumstances).

Having said this (that was about embedding), a web page should also never try to *link* local files with an absolute local pathname like `file://myfolder/mysubfolder/linked_file.pdf` since the browser web should have no info about your personal computer's filesystem. The "myfolder" name itself, but also its pathname, are local information that web developers should try to don't get, and don't use.

If you need to export things:

You can try to export a compressed file, containing the web page and also your PDF files. So, the user extracts everything, and you can rely on your relative structure, with predictable relative URLs like `<a href="./files/file.pdf">...</a>` etc.

Comment: Exporting a compressed file with web page and PDF files is a good idea. However, I'm looking for a "pure PDF"-solution where the main document also is a PDF and not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`"./mysubfolder/linked_file.pdf"` should work in many cases, but it can vary from reader to reader and device to device. Thus it is best not to use folders, simply assume same root folder.

Here the HTML links to same root folder i.e. current "downloads"   before save as.

If we hover before print as PDF we can see at bottom left it looks to open current working test.pdf, once printed it should do the same and look for the sibling file.

`<a href="./test.pdf" [other options]>samefolder test.pdf</a>`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried file:///./mysubfolder/linked_file.pdf (pdf in subfolder) and file:///./linked_file.pdf (pdf in same folder as main pdf). Both versions don't work.

Comment: When my link looks like this <a href="test.pdf"</a>, I save webpage as pdf with browser print function, open saved PDF with Acrobat Reader and hover over the link I see that it is pointing to the web ("https://...). I want to point it to local file. So I think that file:/// is necessary.